# Read data in span using Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

```
<div style="float:left;width:100%">

                <span class="scratchPrice" style="font-size:12px;font-weight:normal; color :#999999"><del>Rs&nbsp;2999</del>&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="discountPrice" style="font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;color: #f5615f">(66%&nbsp;off)</span>

            <span style="font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;color:#5a5a5a;width:100%;float:left;">Rs&nbsp;999&nbsp;</span>
            </div>
```

I want to read value Rs.999 using jsoup.
My code is

```
Elements elements1 = document.select("discountPrice");
            productPrice=  elements1.first().text();

            System.out.println(productPrice);
```

and by using this code I got value (66% off)
Please take a look into this code.
Thanking you..

Answer (score 0):

You will get each span as following and than check if its last span.

```
Document doc;
Element div;
Elements span;

div = doc.select("div").get(0); // select the first div.
span = div.select("span");

for (int i = 0; i < span.size(); i++) {
    Element span = span.get(i);

//check here is its last span from div than extract this value will return RS.999
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS query:

```
span.scratchPrice > del
```

[DEMO](http://try.jsoup.org/%7E2eShWIvhAOuzjNPqW8gPWqZpVh8)

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
Element del = document.select("span.scratchPrice > del").first();
System.out.println(del.text());
```